Async method to write spreadsheet repeating entries
On my code, i've got an async class that gets data from a spreadsheet(like social security numbers and contract numbers), scrap data from a website, return this data as an object and then write this object to an excel spreadsheet.
However, i'm facing the following issue: I'm using a semaphore to determine how many instances will run at the same time. So far so good, okay. But when i run two instances at the same time, the information written on the excel spreadsheet repeats. I've noticed that each entry repeats random times(but not ever exceeding the semaphore limit(that's curious).
I've already tried to define an ConcurrentQueue to be thread safe, but this didn't helped much. My goal is to scrap data and write everything into the excel spreadsheet - but to scrap multiple entries at once (and not waiting until one scrap is finished in order to begin the other).
I've also tried to write batches (each 10 entries processed write to the file, but this didn't helped).
This is my code for the ProcessFileService:
public class ProcessFileService : IProcessFileService
{
    private readonly IFileService _fileService;
    private readonly IValidationService _validationService;
    private readonly IWebScrapingService _webScrapingService;
    private readonly IExcelWriterService _excelWriterService;
    private static SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(5, 5); // 5 initial, 5 max
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> _processedEntries = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

    public ProcessFileService(IFileService fileService, IValidationService validationService, IWebScrapingService webScrapingService, IExcelWriterService excelWriterService)
    {
        _fileService = fileService;
        _validationService = validationService;
        _webScrapingService = webScrapingService;
        _excelWriterService = excelWriterService;
    }

    public async Task ProcessFile(string filePath, Action<string> updateStatus)
    {
        var lines = _fileService.ReadFile(filePath);
        updateStatus("Leitura do arquivo concluída. Processando...");
        var validationResults = _validationService.ValidateFile(lines);

        // Use a ConcurrentQueue to safely handle concurrent access
        var queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string[]>(validationResults.Take(20)); // process only 20 entries for example

        updateStatus($"Processando {queue.Count} entradas");

        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        Random rnd = new Random();

        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            if (queue.TryDequeue(out var line))
            {
                var cpfCnpj = line[1];
                var numAcordo = line[0];

                // Check if the entry has already been processed
                if (_processedEntries.TryAdd(cpfCnpj, numAcordo))
                {
                    tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
                    {
                        await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
                        try
                        {
                            updateStatus($"Processando {numAcordo} \\" + $" {cpfCnpj}");
                            await Task.Delay(rnd.Next(1398, 2646));

                            // Process the entry with IWebScrapingService
                            AcordoData acordoData;
                            try
                            {
                                acordoData = await _webScrapingService.ProcessValidEntries(numAcordo, cpfCnpj);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                updateStatus($"Error in IWebScrapingService for {numAcordo}: {ex.Message}");
                                return; // Skip to the next item in the queue
                            }

                            // Write to Excel
                            try
                            {
                                string path = @"C:\SAIDA_PROGRAMA\";
                                string fileName = "SAIDA_BUSCADADOS.xlsx";
                                string finalPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(path + "\\" + fileName);
                                await _excelWriterService.WriteToExcel(acordoData, finalPath);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                updateStatus($"IExcelWriterService error {numAcordo}: {ex.Message}");
                            }

                            // Optionally log or update status
                            updateStatus($"Processado {numAcordo} com sucesso.");
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            updateStatus($"Erro processando {numAcordo}: {ex.Message}");
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            _semaphore.Release();
                        }
                    }));
                }
            }
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}

And this is the class who does all the writing:
public class ExcelWriterService : IExcelWriterService
{
    private static readonly object _fileLock = new object();

    public async Task WriteToExcel(AcordoData acordoData, string filePath)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            lock (_fileLock)
            {
                IWorkbook workbook;
                ISheet sheet;
                bool fileExists = File.Exists(filePath);

                if (fileExists)
                {
                    // Open the existing file
                    using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
                    }
                    sheet = workbook.GetSheetAt(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Create a new file
                    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
                    sheet = workbook.CreateSheet("AcordoData");

                    // Add headers
                    IRow headerRow = sheet.CreateRow(0);
                    headerRow.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("Número Acordo");
                    headerRow.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("Número CPF ou CNPJ");
                    headerRow.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue("Dias de atraso");
                    headerRow.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue("Situação");
                    headerRow.CreateCell(4).SetCellValue("Data Interrupção / Primeira parcela em aberto");
                    headerRow.CreateCell(5).SetCellValue("Saldo Acordo");
                }

                // Find the next available row
                int rowNum = sheet.LastRowNum + 1;
                IRow row = sheet.CreateRow(rowNum);

                // Add data
                row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(acordoData.NumAcordo);
                row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue(acordoData.CpfCnpj);
                row.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue(acordoData.DiasEmAtraso);
                row.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue(acordoData.Situacao);

                if (acordoData.Situacao == "Interrompido")
                {
                    row.CreateCell(4).SetCellValue(acordoData.DataInterrupcao);
                }
                else if (acordoData.Situacao == "Em Atraso" || acordoData.Situacao == "Em Dia")
                {
                    row.CreateCell(4).SetCellValue(acordoData.ParcelData.Vencimento);
                }

                row.CreateCell(5).SetCellValue(acordoData.SaldoAcordo);

                // Write the file
                if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath));
                }

                using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    workbook.Write(fs);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}


why not just put all the data in memory first?  DataSet?  Then write the file when done.  Selenium is inherently non-async.  Once action happens and then another...  to multi-thread a Selenium script you need a thread per browser/driver pair.  Coordinating those threads to get separate data will be a bit of a pain.  I'd use a single thread here or at least a separate excel file/dataset for each thread.

what if i tell you that i recently had this idea hahahh! why don't i just write to the memory and then to the spreadsheet? however i'm about to change things and abandon selenium ; trying to sniff the http requests and create a code using HttpClient (problem is being the authentication, others operation i have already identified). Selenium needs to open chromedriver, browse the page, you need to pray for your conditions to work (element.isclickable or isvisible doesn't return the expected results always).
